# Authoritative Copy DocuSign REST API

Tags: docusignapi

Can anyone help me on getting Authoritative copy from DocuSign using REST api call. I am not able to find any resources to get the authoritative copy. Tried using DocuSign SOAP API(JAVA SDK web example). got below error while getting the connection.
ul 30, 2013 2:30:46 PM org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromClass
INFO: Creating Service {http://www.docusign.net/API/Credential}CredentialSoapService from class net.docusign.credential.CredentialSoap
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.calcXmlName(PropertyInfoImpl.java:287)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.calcXmlName(PropertyInfoImpl.java:260)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl.getTypes(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:100)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeElementPropertyInfoImpl.getTypes(RuntimeElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:50)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.size(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:42)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.hasNext(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:139)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:49)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:41)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:189)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:204)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$3.run(JAXBContextImpl.java:352)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$3.run(JAXBContextImpl.java:350)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:349)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.(JAXBContextImpl.java:215)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:76)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:265)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.createContext(JAXBContextCache.java:265)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.getCachedContextAndSchemas(JAXBContextCache.java:172)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.createJAXBContextAndSchemas(JAXBDataBinding.java:464)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:330)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:478)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:690)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:540)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:252)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:205)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:90)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:156)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:156)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:93)
    at net.docusign.sample.CredentialFactory.getCredential(CredentialFactory.java:38)
    at net.docusign.sample.DocuSignExpore.getToken(DocuSignExpore.java:20)
    at net.docusign.sample.DocuSignExpore.main(DocuSignExpore.java:25)

Answer (score 0):

The [SOAP API guide](http://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm) has a few pages that describe how to get the Authoritative Copy.  Basically, it's not just one API call but several that you need to make.  I'm not sure what's causing the error you've listed above, not enough info to debug, but the following should help you get this working.

The basic idea is that you need to extract the envelope first, then you obtain a key that allows you to decrypt the docs.  I believe when you obtain the key is when the envelope is deleted from the source location, so that you now have the one and only authoritative copy.

The following pages explain the calls in detail:

[ExportAuthoritativeCopy](http://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Post-Processing%20Group/ExportAuthoritativeCopy.htm)

[AuthoritativeCopyExportDocuments](http://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Post-Processing%20Group/AuthoritativeCopyExportDocuments.htm)

[AcknowledgeAuthoritativeCopyExport](http://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Post-Processing%20Group/AcknowledgeAuthoritativeCopyExport.htm)

[AuthoritativeCopyExportStatus](http://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Post-Processing%20Group/AuthoritativeCopyExportStatus.htm)

Also, the following page has some important rules related to Authoritative copy that you should know about

[Rules for Authoritative Copy](http://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Post-Processing%20Group/Rules%20for%20exporting%20Authoritative%20Copy%20envelopes.htm)

Comment: I want to know, Is DocuSign providing any REST api for Retrieving of Authoritative copy.

Comment: Sorry but it looks like you can enable an authoritative copy to be made through REST api by setting *authoritativeCopy* property to true on a given envelope.  Retrieving the copy is only possible through SOAP at the moment.  Not sure if and when this will change.