# What is "ACHolder" field in docusign connect xml?

Tags: docusignapi

I was looking for some explanation on the fields that are being used in docusign connect sample xml which will be pushed to my listener application. I see following fields but not sure what does it mean. Whose information will be provided there?

```
<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>
.
.
.
<ACStatus>Original</ACStatus>
<ACStatusDate>2010-06-26T09:16:21.27</ACStatusDate>
<ACHolder>ACHolder Name</ACHolder>
<ACHolderEmail> ACHolder.email@address.com </ACHolderEmail>
<ACHolderLocation>ACHolder Location</ACHolderLocation>
.
.
.
</DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>
```

Answer (score 0):

### ACHolder = Authoritative Copy Holder

Ergin does a really good job explaining all of the details in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17957926/1612605